# Send a Response with an inexact Content-Length header then manually end it

Tags: httpresponse, http-content-length

I'm in a situation where I'm sending a file to an MP3 player, and this player needs to know the file length to show progress bar properly. The problem is that this MP3 comes from a file that is the result of an on-the-fly conversion, so I cannot know the final file size. Just an estimate (Bitrate * duration). So, when setting an erroneous Content-Length for the file, the file cannot be served, the download being hanging at the end with a network error.

Is there a way to force browsers to accept the data as final and as-is? For the player, this is not a problem, since it will probably just stops if it reaches an end sooner than it should.

[Edit]

For now, I'll try to add '00' bytes until I reach the good size and see how it is played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't need any ID3 tag information, the solution for this specific MP3 problem was to:

1. Use a tool like ffprobe.exe to get the duration
2. Remove 2 seconds to be sure to not reach the end of the real MP3 file with an unknown size before you have sent the number of bytes specified in your content-length header.
3. Then multiply by the bitrate, so you get the estimated size for the MP3 with an unknown size, then you remove some kbs.

   ```
   Function getduration(ByVal url As String, ByVal curqual As Integer) As String            
   Dim path As String = "C:\cmd\"
   Dim app As String = MapPath(".") & "\ffprobe.exe"

   Dim myProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
   Dim AppPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath 
   myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = app
   myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = url
   myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
   myProcess.Start()

   Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardError
   Dim str As String = mystreamreader.ReadToEnd
   Dim loca As Integer = str.IndexOf("Duration:") + 10
   Dim locb As Integer = str.IndexOf(",", loca)
   Dim tm As String = str.Substring(loca, locb - loca)
   Dim tim As Integer = TimeSpan.Parse(tm).TotalMilliseconds
   Dim siz As Long = (((tim - 2000) * curqual) / 8)
   Return siz
   End Function
   ```